# Xterm is not completely erasing field lines

Tags: xterm

We have a SSH tunnel to a remote unix box from Windows clients using Cygwin. It launches a terminal program from the unix box locally on the Windows box for data input.

The xterm window is launched as follows

```
xterm -fn 10x20 -bg DodgerBlue4 -fg white -cr white -ls -geometry 90x30 -e program
```

When a screen goes from read only mode to edit mode, the edit fields have __________. When going back to read only mode, a single pixel artifact is left behind for each field.

```
*readonly*
User:

*edit*
User: ___________

*after edit exit*
User:           .    <- this dot is left behind
```

Any idea what we need to change to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try a different font or print a space after the user name.

Alternatively, look for a different terminal emulator. Konsole (which needs KDE) is probably overkill but there are many emulators that are much better than xterm. Try rxvt or something from [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_terminal_emulators).

Comment: I should of mentioned we don't have the ability to edit the unix scripts. I will play with the fonts.